# Is there a way to get a localized date/time based on a U.S format string?

Tags: java, date, localization

I'm not sure these cases are possible, but I have format strings for a US locale,

```
1.  ccc \'at\' h:m a
2.  yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

I want to format a Date object into another locale using the analagous format strings.  For example, "**Wed at 2:30 PM**" should render as "**Miercoles a la 10:30 am**" in spanish.

Calendar.getDateInstance is great for localization, but relies on predefined integer constants that represent formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you will need to [create an instance with the target Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-). If you are using a [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) style, you would need to [get an instance for the target locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance-int-java.util.Locale-).

In both cases, it appears you want to [change the timezone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone-java.util.TimeZone-) also.

Comment: thanks, I tried using SimpleDateFormat, but that doesn't convert the "at" word.

Comment: @MarcusH, you will have to translate "at" yourself.

Comment: @Zielu: This is not link-only, by virtue of mentioning at least the basics of what to do in the link potholes. "Create/get an instance of SimpleDateFormat/DateFormat with the target Locale, then change the timezone" is acceptable with no links at all, and when you add that the method names are right there in the URLs....